# Spinner empty, trying to populate with SimpleCursorAdaptor in subroutine

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to populate a spinner with data from a database.  The code is in a subroutine.  Everything executes but the spinner is empty.  If I copy the code to the "onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) it works fine.  I am thinking I have  context issue but can not figure it out.

Here is the subroutine:

```
public void showMatchNames (){      
    Cursor c;

    String sMatchName = "MatchTable";        
    c = db.query(sMatchName, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){

        SimpleCursorAdapter MatchAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, new String[]{KEY_TITLE}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        MatchAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spin2.setAdapter(MatchAdapter);
    }
    scrMatchView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySpinnerListener());            
    c.close(); // Done with Cursor so close it
}
```

There is data in the database, confirmed by exporting to SQliteMan and doing a query.
I can also pull the names from the database and populate the spinner with a simple ArrayAdapter from the "showMatchNames" subroutine.

I am pretty sure it is something simple but I have been staring at this for hours now and can't get it to work.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: {banging head on desk}
DON'T CLOSE THE CURSOR!!

Once I removed the c.close it is working fine.  That was only 6 hours I will never get back.  Anyways thanks for looking and maybe that will help someone else having similar issues.